# Using jquery how to get json data via ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to get JSON data from a php file and pass those values to a dropdown. I made used jquery autocomplete by remote jsonp datasource example and its working fine now i wanted to use dropdown instead of autocomplete by clicking event. i tried using the below code but its not working

[image]

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$("#getAddr").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'json.php', //your server side script
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        postcode: request.term
                    },

                    success: function (data) {

                        //if multiple results are returned
                        if(data.Addresses instanceof Array)

                            response ($.map(data.Addresses, function (item) {
                                return {

                        listItems+= "<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>";

                               $("#DLState").html(listItems);


                                }
                            }));
                    }




                });



});


</script>
```

Here is the json file

```
<?php
 $postcode = urlencode($_POST['postcode']);
//$postcode ="E145AA";
 $username = "api-key";
$password = "LG5345gdg34";
$remote_url = 'https://api.getAddress.io/uk/'.$postcode;

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
 )
);

 $context = stream_context_create($opts);

 // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
 $file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

//$file='{"Latitude":-0.020223,"Longitude":51.504859,"Addresses":["Abbey Offices Ltd, 1    
 Canada Square, LONDON","B B V A, 1 Canada Square, LONDON","B P R Interiors Ltd, 1 
 Canada Square, LONDON","Citihub Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON","Coutts & Co, 1 Canada 
  Square, LONDON","Diligence Ltd, 1 Canada Square, LONDON","Doctors of the World UK, 1   
   Canada Square, 

print_r($file);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?  Specifically how/where does it fail?

Comment: entire code is not working ...even i dont know this code is right or wrong :(

Comment: I'm afraid "it isn't working" just doesn't meaningfully describe the problem.  What indication do you have that it isn't doing what you expect?  Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?  Any server-side errors in the PHP logs?  When you debug this, what happens?  Where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it have the expected data?  What is the server's response?  You need to put in at least *some* effort.  We can't run this on your computer *for you*.

Comment: yes i understood ..give me a min to update my query

Comment: now i updated the question

Comment: i want to know what i am doing is right or wrong approch?

Comment: Well, there's a syntax error in the PHP code.  The first line starting with `Canada` is probably producing errors.  You should definitely check your PHP logs for errors when something isn't working as expected.  As for the rest, I'm afraid taking a screen shot of the button you're clicking doesn't really *describe* how it's failing.  This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with debugging tools.  They will be *invaluable* in your development efforts.  Browsers have built-in debugging tools, such as Firebug or Chrome tools, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what you're trying to do, but a few comments:

dataType is what you're expecting back from the server, not what you're sending. Use contentType.

Try to return the ajax call and chaining them together with a done() function instead of embedding the success. This makes the code more readable.

Stringify the request so that you're sending a json encoded string instead of a javascript object.

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var onSuccess = function (data) {
                    //if multiple results are returned
                    if(data.Addresses instanceof Array)
                        response ($.map(data.Addresses, function (item) {
                            return {
                    listItems+= "<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>";
                           $("#DLState").html(listItems);
                            }
                        }));
                }
var postSomething = function(){
 return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/json.php', //your server side script
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    postcode: request.term
                })
            });
});

$("#getAddr").click(function(){
    postSomething().done(onSuccess);
}


</script>
```